# Java regular expression deconstruction for duplicate characters

Tags: java, regex

I want to understand the following regex:

```
String.replaceAll("(.)(?=.*\\1)", "")
```

I understand the first part `(.)` is used to group a single character (anything). This is to create a back reference for `\\1`.

The other part `(?=.*\\1)`I am confused on. It says previous character 1 or 0 times followed by (not sure what `=` is), followed by any character 1 or more times, followed by a back reference.

If I input the following `hello12hel` it removes the duplicates. Can you explain how it is matching the duplicate?

Another question I had is that why a grouping is required on `(?=.*\\1)`. Regex fails when it is not provided (i.e. if I do `String.replaceAll((.)?=.*\\1)` ). (Also why can't we use $1 instead of `\\1`?)

Comment: `(?=.*\\1)` is a look-ahead that checks whether there is the same character in the rest of the string, after you match and capture the character in `(.)`. Look-ahead doesn't consume the string, so the next match can occur on the next index, instead of where you find `\1`. With this method, all the instances of a character will be removed, except for the last instance.

Comment: `$1` is the syntax in the replacement string. It can't be used in the regular expression.

Comment: Thanks! Referred to the regex syntax on Stackoverflow and it had what you mentioned.